# Can I get the final output video dimensions before encoding with ffmpeg?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

Hello world :) (first msg, beginner level ;) )

I'm trying to write a small msdos script to simply resize vids.

First, with ffprobe I get `iw`,`ih`,DAR,SAR from the source then I choose a desired output height oH. I use this simple cmd line to let ffmpeg calculate the output width and do the job:

`ffmpeg -i !in! -ss !t1! -to !t2! -filter:v scale=-2:!oH!,setsar=1,setdar=!dar! -c:a copy !out!`

I take the example of the output width in a simple case because calculation is easy, and the -2 value of the scale filter should give an output width of `ow=trunc(oh*a/2)*2`

But life is not as simple! and sometimes I add/play with other options like crop or other effects, etc... The automatic calculation with -1 or -2 is useful but I would need to check if the final dimensions computed by ffmpeg will be what I expect before I run the whole script.

Thus, my question: is there a way to get an estimation on some data of the output video before running ffmpeg, using any ffmpeg tool?

- I didn't find any "simulation run" option (with no encoding) which could give some data, at least those that are predictable.
- I also thought of using ffplay since it can takes the same arguments and process the video 'on the fly' and tried different -loglevel values:
  `ffplay -i !in! -vf "scale=-2:!oH!" -loglevel trace`
  but I can't find the output dimensions anywhere... although the video is actually playing...
- (last idea while writing: it seems ffmpeg can extract and process a single picture from the video, then I would have to analyse it; but it would be an additional step and more time consuming for a batch run)

any suggestion? thank you!

Comment: Not possible, per se. You can add `showinfo` as the last video filter and set output options as `-vframes 1 -map 0:v -f null -` (after removing the output filename). You will then have to parse the showinfo output to locate this substring e.g. `s:640x480`

Comment: Found it! Thank you for the trick and the cmd line parameters.

 This worked for me:
`ffmpeg  -i !in! -vframes 1 -map 0:v -filter:v scale=-2:!oH!,showinfo  -f null !out! >!log! 2>&1`

 Then I extract the metadata using ffprobe:
`ffprobe -i !out! -v quiet -show_entries stream=width,height -select_streams v:0 -of csv=p=0`

 But, while I can see the correct SAR and DAR of the rescaled vid with 'ffmpeg -vf showinfo', ffprobe doesn't give the correct values for 'stream=sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio' : I get '0:1' for both instead of, say, 1:1 and 16:9.